# when std::map::insert finds the element, it still constructs an instance of the object. How can I stop this?

Tags: c++, standard-library

I have a std::map of objects whose instances are very expensive to construct. (In real life they require several accesses to a database.)

I want to access an element of the map, or create it if it doesn't exist. This sounds like a job for std::map::insert, except that the expensive object is constructed unnecessarily and then thrown away if the element exists. To illustrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct CexpensiveObject
{    
    CexpensiveObject(const char* args="default"):args_(args)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor: CexpensiveObject(" << args << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    CexpensiveObject( const CexpensiveObject& other )
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor: CexpensiveObject other.args_ = " << other.args_ << "." << std::endl;
        args_ = other.args_;
    }
    ~CexpensiveObject()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor: CexpensiveObject args_ = " << args_ << "." << std::endl;
    }
    const char* args_;
};

// entry point
int main() 
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, CexpensiveObject> mymaptype;   
    mymaptype mymap;
    std::pair<mymaptype::iterator, bool> insertionResult;

    std::cout << "First insertion" << std::endl;
    insertionResult = mymap.insert( mymaptype::value_type( "foobar", CexpensiveObject("first") ) );
    std::cout << "Was it inserted? " << (insertionResult.second?"yes":"no") << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Second insertion" << std::endl;
    insertionResult = mymap.insert( mymaptype::value_type("foobar", CexpensiveObject("second") ) );
    std::cout << "Was it inserted? " << (insertionResult.second?"yes":"no") << std::endl;
}
```

Results:

```
First insertion
Constructor: CexpensiveObject(first)
Copy Constructor: CexpensiveObject other.args_ = first.
Copy Constructor: CexpensiveObject other.args_ = first.
Destructor: CexpensiveObject args_ = first.
Destructor: CexpensiveObject args_ = first.
Was it inserted? yes
Second insertion
Constructor: CexpensiveObject(second)
Copy Constructor: CexpensiveObject other.args_ = second.
Destructor: CexpensiveObject args_ = second.
Destructor: CexpensiveObject args_ = second.
Was it inserted? no
Destructor: CexpensiveObject args_ = first.
```

There's more copying and destroying than I expected, but critically an instance CexpensiveObject is constructed and then thrown away if an element with the same key exists in the ma.

Am I misusing std::map::insert, or do I have to use std::map::find to check whether an element with the same key exists before I instantiate a CexpensiveObject instance?

Comment: There was one constructor call, not counting the copy constructor, and it was explicit in your code. Are you saying your *copy* constructor is expensive and requires database accesses?

Comment: @David Schwartz: There were two constructor calls, one where the element was inserted and the other where it wasn't. The second one is the problem as it's constructed an object but not used it.  The copy constructor (and the destructors) aren't a problem but I'm surprised at there being two of them at each insert.

Comment: @Mark Taylor: thanks for correcting my embarrassing title typo. I didn't realise it's possible to change titles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's constructed before you even get to `insert`, when you call `CexpensiveObject("second")`. You're *passing in* the extraneous object! (And then it's copied as the `value_type` is passed to `insert`.)

Instead of `insert`, use `find`. If you find the item at the desired key, then you're finished. If not, *then* insert it.

```
auto it = mymap.find("foobar");
if (it == mymap.end())
  mymap.insert(mymaptype::value_type("foobar", CexpensiveObject("second")));
```

Comment: It also might be worth using `lower_bound` instead, as for the cost of another key comparison, you can eliminate having to find the insertion point a second time.  For large maps, this can save time.

Comment: This was my workaround while I was trying to understand what insert does exactly. Looks like the best solution. I had wondered if insert was doing some kind of template thing to avoid the object being created unnecessarily, but evidently not!

Comment: @ Dave S: Good point. In my case the maps are quite small, but as you point out this can significantly improve performance for larger maps.

Answer (score 1):

Use find to check if the element should be inserted to save up some work if the object already exists.

Sadly map::insert calls your copy constructor a lot of times. If this is unaccetable, and you can use c++11, take a look at map::emplace_insert. If you must use C++03, IIRC [boost container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container.html) has a map which uses internally [Boost move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/move.html) to emulate move semantics.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm cross compiling and I don't have  a very recent C++ compiler available for the target platform. We haven't included boost in our list of permissible libraries yet, though in my opinion we should at least use the boost header-only parts. The joys of trying to maintain a rigidly standard development environment...!